# Is Http Session contradicted with Http Stateless?

Tags: http

As we all know, HTTP is stateless. That means, the server side will not store any information about the client side. But when we write code with C#, we may use Http Session to store some data for the user client, for example, the order information of a online shop application. Is this contradicted?

I think, a explanation may be that the word stateless is to Each Connection. Every time it gets a request, and when the response is send out, the connection is closed and destroyed.

Could you guys tell me why this is not contradicted? Thank you.

Information to be updated:

***The core HTTP protocol itself is stateless (if you ignore persistent connections, caching, etc), but servers that implement HTTP, and web applications built on top of HTTP do not have to be stateless***

Answer (score 8):

> As we all know, HTTP is stateless. That means, the server side will not store any information about the client side.

The core HTTP protocol itself is stateless (if you ignore persistent connections, caching, etc), but servers that implement HTTP, and web applications built on top of HTTP do not have to be stateless in the sense that you mean.  Indeed, there associated standards for passing session identifying information; e.g. using cookies.  And you don't even need cookies.  Session tokens can be passed as part of the URL ...

Please provide links to the source or sources that lead you to believe that HTTP servers will not store information about the client side ... so that we can get to the root of your misunderstanding.

---

> I think, a explanation may be that the word stateless is to Each Connection. Every time it gets a request, and when the response is send out, the connection is closed and destroyed.

That is more or less correct.  (With persistent connections, the connection is NOT destroyed when the response is sent.)

But that doesn't in any way support your assertion that sessions contradict HTTP statelessness.  Sessions exist at a conceptual level above the core HTTP protocol.

---

Maybe the real source of your misunderstanding is the term *stateless protocol*.   According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol):

> *"In computing, a stateless protocol is a communications protocol in which no session information is retained by the receiver, usually a server. Relevant session data is sent to the receiver by the client in such a way that every packet of information transferred can be understood in isolation, without context information from previous packets in the session."*

The HTTP protocol is stateless in this sense.  An HTTP request and response can be understood in isolation from another request / response.  Basic HTTP doesn't rely on sessions.  (By contrast, the TCP protocol fundamentally relies on keeping track of sequence numbers across multiple packets.)

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol#Stacking_of_stateless_and_stateful_protocol_layers) then says this:

> *"There can be complex interactions between stateful and stateless protocols among different protocol layers. For example, HTTP is an example of a stateless protocol layered on top of TCP, a stateful protocol, which is layered on top of IP, another stateless protocol, which is routed on a network that employs BGP, another stateful protocol, to direct the IP packets riding on the network."*

> *"This stacking of layers continues even above HTTP. As a workaround for the lack of a session layer in HTTP, HTTP servers implement various session management methods, typically utilizing a unique identifier in the cookie or parameter that allows the server to track requests originating from the same client, and effectively creating a stateful protocol on top of HTTP."*.

What this is saying is that "HTTP sessions" (implemented via cookies, for example) are a protocol layer **above** the HTTP protocol layer.  Hence the do not "contradict" the statelessness of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Hello, "Http server is stateless" is just based on my opinion, and maybe I am limited. Thank you for your idea, and I will change the content of my question, to add some information.